Find a service on local network from Ubuntu guest on VMBox Windows Host
I'm using VMBox 7.0.18 installed Ubuntu Guest on it. I tried different means to communicate to my .local services from the guest with no success. Neither NAT or Bridged configuration succeeded in that.
I need the DNS-SD in exact (no workarounds as port forwarding, or accessing by IP) because the tool I'm using rely on DNS-SD, and it's available on Linux systems.
How can I achieve this?

Here are some possibly useful command executes:
$ uname -a
Linux Ubuntu 6.8.0-45-generic #45~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Sep 11 15:25:05 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ nslookup rpipicow.local

;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.53

Server:     127.0.0.53

Address:    127.0.0.53#53



** server can't find rpipicow.local: SERVFAIL

$ ifconfig

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500

        inet 192.168.100.173  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.100.255

        inet6 fe80::f2d7:1072:a8d5:2566  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>

        ether 08:00:27:a5:ec:d7  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)

        RX packets 7216  bytes 7622267 (7.6 MB)

        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0

        TX packets 2076  bytes 188481 (188.4 KB)

        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536

        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0

        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>

        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)

        RX packets 196  bytes 18448 (18.4 KB)

        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0

        TX packets 196  bytes 18448 (18.4 KB)

        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0



Turns out that nslookup is the wrong command to discover mDNS local services, now I've tested with avahi-browse -a and it successfully discovers them.
The tested network adapter is Bridged.
